# Odd Canvas Clipping Behavior

Tags: html5-canvas

What I'm trying to do here is to draw a ListBox in Canvas.  I'm trying to use clip() to hide list items not in the ListBox "viewport."  The problem is that all list items not in the ListBox "viewport" are correctly hidden except for the last list item.  I've noticed that if I only call requestAnimationFrame once, the last list item will be clipped correctly.  Alternatively, if I call beginPath after drawing the list item(s), the last list item will be clipped correctly.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="300" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas> 

<script type="text/javascript">

    window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

        var colors = ["green", "yellow", "blue", "red"];

        var gameLoopCallbackWrapper = function () {
            //Comment this line out to fix clipping anomaly
            window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoopCallbackWrapper);

            if (ctx) { ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 200, 300); }

            ctx.save();

            ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, 1, 100, 100);

            //draw list box
            ctx.lineWidth = 1;
            ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
            ctx.rect(-26, -15, 52, 30);
            ctx.stroke();

            ctx.clip();

            //draw list items
            for (var key in colors) {
                var color = colors[key];

                ctx.save();

                ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 14 * key - 8);

                ctx.fillStyle = color;

                ctx.strokeStyle = "black";

                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.rect(-25, -7, 50, 14);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.fill();

                ctx.restore();

                //uncomment this line to see clipping anomally fixed
                //ctx.beginPath();
            }

            ctx.restore();
        };

        window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoopCallbackWrapper);
    });
</script>
```

The code above is a simplified version of my code meant only to demonstrate the clipping anomaly.  It is not interactive in its current form, so list items cannot be dragged up and down.

Comment: You have to call `beginPath` at start of your function, otherwise your rect will just accumulate to the last drawn path (even if cleared by clearRect)

Comment: Good call; thank you for that. I put ctx.beginPath right before starting the draw the list box and the last list item is now properly clipped.  Can you tell I'm new to Canvas? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

"You have to call beginPath at start of your function, otherwise your rect will just accumulate to the last drawn path (even if cleared by clearRect)" – Kaiido

"Good call; thank you for that. I put ctx.beginPath right before starting the draw the list box and the last list item is now properly clipped. Can you tell I'm new to Canvas? ;-)" – Meadock